# Strange local IP address

Tags: ip

So, my computer "thinks" that it's IP address is 25.73.213.34 . Tracert-ing that IP confirms that it is my computer's IP. But this IP doesn't look like a local address, and when i looked up it in an IP ->location website, it said that this is an English IP (I'm in Hungary). Is this normal?

Comment: Are you on a home network? Did your router give you the Above IP? and is this a Recent find?

Comment: That does not fall under the Private IP range. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: Are you running a VPN?

Comment: please repost what's coming in your shell when you enter `ifconig`

Comment: Why don't you call your ISP And ask them? And elaborate on whether that IP is when you do ipconfig/ifconfig, or whether it's shown when you go to www.whatismyip.com

Comment: According to 'whois' the entire 25.x.x.x is owned by the UK ministry of defence. So this looks not normal. Maybe a error from your ISP? Try renewing the DHCP lease. Alternative source: https://db-ip.com/25.73.213.34

Comment: Where did you see this address? Are you using Hamachi?

Comment: Oh yes, hamachi... I forgot that. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was [Hamachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogMeIn_Hamachi) VPN! I forgot I had that installed. It uses that IP address range for its VPN these days and that's what it had picked up